# cannot set up lm-sensors propetly

Tags: debian, monitoring, temperature, amd, sensors

### I actually try to get lm-sensors to work as I wish.

And my only wish is to see how the cpu is doing.
(Optional HDD's, FSB and I'm open your suggestions)

So I run **Debian wheezy**, and did a
`apt-get install lm-sensors`

After that I did a `sensors-detect`.
I said yes to all scans except the I2C/SMBus (because it says it is not safe and not because I know what I'm doing)

And when I do `sensors`, this is what I get :

```
Adapter: PCI adapter 
power1:      117.56 W  (crit = 124.95 W)

k10temp-pci-00c3 Adapter: PCI adapter 
temp1:        +12.9°C  (high =+70.0°C) (crit = +70.0°C, hyst = +68.0°C)
```

My CPU is a **AMD FX(tm)-8120** and i did not install any kind of drivers.
(I looked in the internet but cannot find a equivalent method *needed* like in Windows)

**EDIT:**
So why am I only seeing the 2 entries?
One shows the Watt, I don't really need this.
and the other is like 12,9°C, this is quite unrealistic because I think i should be around 40-50° based on my experience.

**EDIT2:**
`sensors-detect` output

> Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
>   Just press ENTER
>   to continue:
>
> Driver `fam15h_power' (autoloaded):
>     * Chip`AMD Family 15h power sensors' (confidence: 9)
>
> Driver `k10temp' (autoloaded): 
>     * Chip`AMD Family 15h thermal sensors' (confidence: 9)
>
> No modules to load, skipping modules configuration.
>
> Unloading cpuid... OK

Comment: I don't see an actual question being asked here.

Comment: @psusi i edited the question, i hope this brig it out more

Comment: That does not look like your CPU's temperature. Didn't `sensors-detect` tell you to load any modules? Could you post the output of `sensors-detect`?

Comment: @terdon i aded as you wished, or would it be more usefull i post the hole output?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think the rest of the output will be useful but you could put it in a [pastebin](http://debian.pastebin.com) just in case. Is this a laptop or a desktop? Based on your CPU, I assume this is a desktop. Did you build it? Perhaps the sensors are simply not there.

Comment: Yes it is a desktop and yes i did build it by myself.

Comment: OK, you might simply not have connected the motherboard's sensors to the CPU. Have a look at your MB's manual.

Comment: Also, make sure the modules are loaded, try `lsmod | grep k10_temp`.

Comment: I cannot look at the computer right now and nether the manual since everything is in a friends house(more bandwith) but i will look at it tomorrow, or even this evening! And the `lsmod | grep k10_temp` has no output!

Comment: The temperature is unrealistic and this is a known problem with k10temp, but what other readings are you expecting?

Comment: well i will take a look at terdons suggestion and i wish i could see harddisks, powersupply, front side bus..

Comment: @derty (remember to ping me with @ in front of my username or I won't see new comments) if `lsmod | grep k10_temp` has no output, that means that the module is not loaded and sensors-detect said you need it. Try again after running `sudo modprobe k10temp fam15h_power`.

Comment: @terdon I wached at the manual of the motherboard, and there were no specifiq explanations about how the temperature is messured. Neither where there some free pins that where marked for use of mesuring any kind of heat. But i was able to see the cores temperature when navigating in BIOS. Unfortunatly running `sudo modprobe k10temp fam15h_power` and afterwards `sensors-detect` has no other effect that the previous trys.

Comment: Where the modules loaded? Did `lsmod` show them?

Comment: @terdon `lsmod | grep fam15h_power` output is *fam15h_power 12677  0*. But `lsmod | grep k10_temp` has no output. And i dont know where the modules are loaded. Where should they usually be?